# how to select multiple file using jquery.MultiFile.js plugin? selecting multiple file a a time with Individual close buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to select multiple files at a time with individual close buttons?

using jquery.MultiFile.js and jquery.MetaData.js

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the accept if you only want files of a certain extension to be selected Separate valid extensions with a "|", like this: "jpg|gif|png". Server-side validation is always required.

```
<input type="file" class="multi" accept="gif|jpg" maxsize="20000" maxfile="5000" />
```

// limit total pay load size, for total size of all files

> maxsize

// limit individual file size

> maxfile

// size options are accepted in kylobytes

Comment: maxsize, maxfile attributes are provided by jquery.multifile.min.js plugin, please provide url from where you downloaded jquery.multifile.min.js plugin

Comment: And when I select multiple file at a time all are coming in a single line as bunch. I need then as individual list?

Comment: when I select multiple files at a time, each file with close button.??